# Calls to isSumbitted() and isValid() result in "undefined method" error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have a Symfony form that is created from createFormBuilder() in the controller. But under two IF statements the form should carry two different set of fields. My Symfony version is 3.4.

> /src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

Ex: This is the basic form.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('name', TextType::class, ['required' => true]])
    ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['required' => true]])
    ->getForm();

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```

Now I need to append few more fields to this basic form when a condition becomes true. Shown below is what I did and it gives me an error.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['required' => true]])
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['equired' => true]]);

if($a==true){
    $form->add('username', TextType::class, ['required' => true]])
         ->add('password', PasswordType::class, ['required' => true]]);
}

$form->getForm();

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```

The error is:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "isSubmitted" of class
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder".

How can I get this done? Append fields at multiple occasions under different conditions?

Comment: Using $form->getForm()->isSubmitted() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$formbuilder = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['required' => true]])
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['equired' => true]]);

if($a==true){
    $formbuilder->add('username', TextType::class, ['required' => true]])
         ->add('password', PasswordType::class, ['required' => true]]);
}

$form = $formbuilder->getForm();

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```